# Access and uplinks ports QoS Queuing model

Tags: switch, qos

On an access switch, does the uplinks egress QoS Queuing model (multiple traffic classes and bandwidth reservation), should be different than the access ports egress Queuing model ?

Is there a sense of defining different egress policy-map, with different bandwidth reservation, for access ports and uplinks ports ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model is roughly the same, but the marking is different (swap source and destination), and you may allocate queues differently due to higher bandwidth.